# php dll module not found

Tags: php, windows, apache, dll

My `php_stats.dll` always gives a

```
"The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"
```

in Apache error log.

My set up **XAMPP 32 bit** in a Windows 10 64 bit machine.  PHP with XAMPP (so 32 bit too, downloaded last week so up to date).

Had to install into D drive due to windows security
**PHP_stats.dll** - all versions from 1.0.5 to 2.0.3, all 32 bit, non thread safe and thread safe tried again dowloaded last week (yes I've tried the 64 bit version too)

**php_stats.dll** is in *D:/xampp/php/ext/* and *D:/xampp/apache/bin/* (and c:\windows and c:\windows\system32 too out of despiration)

**php.ini** extensions folder is set to *extension_dir="D:/xampp/php/ext/"*, and **http.confg** uses

```
D:/xampp/apache/bin
extension=php_stats.dll in php.ini
```

Windows path set to include php directory (even the ext folder explicitly) and apache directories

I have run `regsvr32 php_stats.dll` (from system32 and the 64 bit version tried too) to register the dll

All with no change to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

For reference and all other people who come here:

Something similar happened to me. I tried enabling php_mailparse extension, which depends on mbstring extension.

It just so happened that I put the extension=php_mailparse.dll line exactly over extension=php_mbstring.dll.

```
extension=php_mailparse.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

It makes sense though, that first mbstring has to be loaded, then mailparse. So I changed the order and it worked.

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mailparse.dll
```

I suggest you check your dependencies and also check if they are loaded first.